# No sound on laptop speakers on an Acer Aspire 6920

Tags: 12.04, sound, headphones, speakers

**Computer**: Acer Aspire 6920

**Card**: HDA Intel

**Chip**: Realtek ALC889

My problem is that the laptop **build-in** speakers don't play any sound. When i plug in my headphones the sound works normally, the same goes with external speakers. Those work normally like the headphones.

The profile in the Sound settings is **Analog two-way Stereo**.

I am using **Ubuntu 12.04**.

Might trere be any problem with my sound drivers or something similar?

Any form of help appreciated.

Comment: I'm suffaring a lot with this same problem. I've reported a bug here--> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/995684 Please go to the above link and support me one this bug to be solved. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), run:

```
alsamixer
```

And increase the Master volume.

Comment: Sadly doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Go to the sound settings and there is a setting for heaphones/speakers that you change everytime you use headphones or speakers. That's what I did on 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with the sound.

After installing and running the xfce4-mixer tool:

sudo apt-get install xfce4-mixer gstreamer0.10-alsa

The sound was present.

There is also this posting: [How to install gstreamer 1.0 in ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380346/how-to-install-gstreamer-1-0-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the sound settings, output device should be "Analog Output", and Make sure that the volume is not muted and that the volume levels are turned up.