# How to install gstreamer 1.0 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gstreamer

The install given elsewhere in the forum is

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gstreamer-developers/ppa        
sudo apt-get update        
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0*
```

Which isn't currently working for my 12.04 install [see below]

Does anyone have updated info or a fix to the instructions?

I did the above but still fail to find the Gst namesapace, I get the message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "webcam-1.0.py", line 4, in <module>
   gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 48, in require_version
  raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gst not available
```

And to be sure, I redid the above steps and then noticed that the regex idenitifed some libraries that were then not marked for install.  I decided to try one of them explicitly by name and got the below.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gstreamer-developers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
[all went OK]
$ sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libgstreamer1.0-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgstreamer1.0-dev' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had a problem in installing gstreamer1.0*. It was resolved after I installed Gstreamer from Ubuntu Repository

It can be installed with Official Ubuntu [Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=gstreamer).

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer0.10-0-dbg libgstreamer0.10-0 gstreamer0.10-tools gstreamer-tools gstreamer0.10-doc gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-x
```

Comment: Why is the accept answer to how to install gstreamer 1.0 instructions for how how to install gstreamer 0.10 ?

Comment: @Yaur I'm kind of 7 years late, but it's as simple as installing the same packages but the 1.0 version

Comment: @CiroGarcía That is correct as of 14.04 but there were not gstreamer1.0 packages for 12.04 (which is what the question was about)at least not in universe... maybe in some PPA somewhere.